# How can I "store" an object or JSON across content pages in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an application with navigation page and some content pages. One of these content pages, downloads a JSON string from web. It's unnecessary download this JSON every time that this page is called. How can I store the JSON? Currently, I'm storing it to `Application.Current.Properties` but I don't need persistence.

Comment: Asking for the "best" way to do something invites opinions. Better to just ask how to do something; people are unlikely to tell you the worst way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a property in your `App` class and it will be available via `App.Current`

in `App.xaml.cs`

```
public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
```

anywhere in your app

```
var value = ((App)App.Current).MyCustomProperty;
```